# Check if user has recorded activity in the last second

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to detect user if online or offline status with my following code

```
$user_activity = '<span style="color:red">Offline</span>';
$stored_activity = $value['last_activity'];
if (!is_null($stored_activity)) {
    $user_last_activity = new DateTime($stored_activity);
    $current_time = new DateTime("now");

    //$interval = $current_time->getTimestamp() - $user_last_activity->getTimestamp();
    $diff = abs(strtotime($value['last_activity']) - strtotime($current_time));

    if ($interval < 1) {
        $user_activity = 'Online';
    } else {
        $user_activity = 'Online';
    }
} else if (is_null($stored_activity)) {
    $user_activity = '<span style="color:orange">N/A (Refresh)</span>';
}
```

but it always givin me Online even if user offline

i tried

```
$interval = $current_time->getTimestamp() - $user_last_activity->getTimestamp();
```

but it didn't work please any help will be grateful

Comment: Did you notice the typo of declaring `$diff` (never accessing it), then trying to access `$interval` which is only commented out in your whole snippet?  Why would you call `strtotime()` on a DateTime object?  What is your actual intented logic? How recently does a user need to be active to qualify as "Online"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide and dump of your data in `$value` for detailed answer, but based on current code and assuming what `$value` contains, I've made some corrections:

```
$user_activity = '<span style="color:red">Offline</span>';
$stored_activity = $value['last_activity'];

    if (!is_null($stored_activity)) {
        $user_last_activity = new DateTime($stored_activity);
        $current_time = new DateTime("now");
    
        $interval = $current_time->getTimestamp() - $user_last_activity->getTimestamp();
    
        // Assuming a user is considered 'Online' if they were active in the last 1 minute (60 seconds).
        if ($interval < 60) {
            $user_activity = '<span style="color:green">Online</span>';
        }
    } else if (is_null($stored_activity)) {
        $user_activity = '<span style="color:orange">N/A (Refresh)</span>';
    }
    
    echo $user_activity;  // Output the user status
```

You can adjust the 60 `if ($interval < 60) {` value value to whatever time you want (in seconds).

Comment: `else if (is_null($stored_activity))` is not needed. It can be `else`